# Need help to install C SDK and PHP SDK for couchbase server 4.0.0 for UBUNTU 14.0

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, couchbase

I have recently started working on couchbase with laravel 5.2 on UBUNTU 14.04 OS. After I installed everything, I am able to see couchbase admin home page but could not able to access it from my code. Below are the steps I followed. Can someone please check and suggest if I miss anything.

1) Downloaded and installed couchbase server 4.0.0 successfully.

2) Downloaded C SDK as mentioned below

```html
wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu trusty trusty/main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2-core libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-dev
```

Then installed PHP SDK using PECL

```html
sudo pecl install couchbase
```

4) After everything got installed, I have opened my composer.json file in my laravel project and added below line

```html
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "ytake/laravel-couchbase": "^0.2.0"
    },
```

Then ran composer update.

5) My config/databse.php settings

```html
'couchbase' => [
            'driver' => 'couchbase',
            'host' => 'http://localhost',
            'user' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin123',
            'bucket' => 'laravel',
            'persist_conn' => true,
            'display_limit' => 20,
```

6)Tried to access records from "laravel" bucket.
  Homecontroller:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        
      

        \DB::connection('couchbase')
                ->table('laravel')->get();

//        $cb = new Couchbase("http://localhost:8091/", "admin", "admin123", "laravel");
//        $cb->set("a", 101);
//        var_dump($cb->get("a"));
//        
//        $cluster = new CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
//        $bucket = $cluster->openBucket('laravel');
//        $bucket->insert('a', 101);
//        var_dump($bucket->get('a'));
    }

}
```

Issue:#1 There I am getting "FatalErrorException in CouchbaseConnector.php line 35:Class 'CouchbaseCluster' not found".

Issue:#2 I am not able to see "Couchbase" in phpinfo();

Comment: can someone please help?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved after I did below configuration settings and install PHP SDK.

1) Run below commands from terminal.

```html
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

2) Install PHP SDK

```html
pecl install couchbase
```

3) After successfull installation open /etc/php5/cli/php.ini to see couchbase extension automatically added to it.

```html
extension="couchbase.so"
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.
```

4) Run phpinfo() to see couchbase information.